# PSQLException: database does not exist Slick

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, slick, intellij-14

I am learning Slick and I was trying to connect to PostgreSQL database in my Intellij IDEA project. I am running this on Ubuntu 14.04, if it's relevant. Every time I run my application I get an exception: *org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "songs" does not exist*

So here is my code:

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main {

  case class Song(
    id: Int,
    name: String,
    singer: String)

  class SongsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Song](tag, "songs") {
    def id = column[Int]("id")

    def name = column[String]("name")

    def singer = column[String]("singer")

    def * = (id, name, singer) <> (Song.tupled, Song.unapply)
  }

  val db = Database.forConfig("scalaxdb")

  val songs = TableQuery[SongsTable]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Await.result({
      db.run(songs.result).map(_.foreach(row =>
        println("song with id " + row.id + " has name " + row.name + " and a singer is " + row.singer)))
    }, 1 minute)
  }
}
```

application.conf file:

```
scalaxdb = {
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
  properties = {
    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/songs?user=user&password=password"
  }
}
```

build.sbt file:

```
name := "slick-test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.25"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"
```

I would be grateful if someone helped me to find an error!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I have created my 'songs' relation in another db (not the one I was trying to connect to). That is why it could not connect. Now it all works just fine!